# Is there a module that can replace tabbed menus with contextual links?

Tags: routes, navigation

The tabbed menus at the top of node with entries like `View`, `Edit`, `Outline` takes too much space for my liking. In my case I also use the [Node Clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) module which also takes up more space because it uses an action link.

Is there a module to hide the tabbed menu and expand it on demand, or change it to contextual links? I have seen a few examples but they all seem to require changes to existing theme files or modules. Is there one implemented as standalone module?

Comment: I have discovered a sandbox module called  [TabsNoMore](https://drupal.org/sandbox/onkeltem/1730244). It has a bug that only allows it to display all the link only in Edit mode. I am posting a separate question on that bug. If fixed I will post the answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Custom Contextual Links module does this https://drupal.org/project/ccl

Jeff Eaton gives a good overview of this module https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/module-monday-custom-contextual-links

Alternatively, you could theme the existing menu to be styled like contextual links since both use an unordered list, just different css classes that trigger style and javascript behavior.  To do so you could either use a custom module to add the css classes necessary or add your own css rules.

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. I am not quite sure where the problem is. The only thing I can add is I am using Display Suite in case it affects it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_tabs
seems to be for you.

For the clone action, you could use the patch from here:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1252702

There's also the module node_clone_tab, which
turns the clone action into a tab.
But i don't know if this works together with contextual_tabs.